# Composite Pattern reverse order function call

Tags: python, inheritance, composite

I have composite class like that. I want to call component function in reverse order.I mean first deepest child functions are called then the one level up and so on.

In following example i calculate the weight of composite object based on their children.Thus the children weight first calculated then the parent weight calculated based on children weights.

How can i do this? What kin of pattern or algorithm should I use?

```
class Component(object): 
    def __init__(self,desc,weight, *args, **kw):
        self.parent = None
        self.desc = desc
        self.weight_user_defined = weight
    def component_function(self):
        pass
    def setParent(self,parent):
        self.parent=parent

class Leaf(Component):
    def __init__(self,desc,weight,*args, **kw):
        Component.__init__(self,desc,weight, *args, **kw)

    def component_function(self):
        print (self.desc,self.weight_user_defined)

class Composite(Component):
    def __init__(self,desc,weight, *args, **kw):
        Component.__init__(self,desc,weight,*args, **kw)
        self.children = []
        self.weight_calculated = 0.0

    def append_child(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)
        child.setParent(self)

    def remove_child(self, child):
        self.children.remove(child)

    def component_function(self):      
        print (self.desc,self.weight_user_defined)
        for foo in self.children:
            foo.component_function()
```

As an example:

```
ROOT (X kg)
    GLOCARY (Y kg)
        Apple  2.1 kg
        Banana 3.2 kg
    MISC (Z kg)  
        Stuff1 3.3 kg
        Stuff2 0.7 kg
```

Thus in order to find X, Y and Z first calculated. (or may be the leaves. eg. quantity*item price)

Comment: I can't see that you're actually calculating anything. You're just printing the weights of the composite and all its children. I guess by calculation, you mean that you would like to cumulatively sum the weights of the children?

Comment: Yes Filip, you are right. I want to cumulatively sum the weight. Instead of print, i want to perform the sum.

Comment: I see. You mentioned that you want the function called in the deepest child first? Why is that, it makes sense to me if we just call the parent, then recursively call down until we hit the deepest child.

Comment: Hi Filip, i edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note:* I wasn't sure what you meant by "reverse order function call", but this is how you would calculate the weight of a composite based on the children.

---

A `Composite` with no children will always have `weight=0`. I didn't think it would make sense for a `Composite` to have `weight!=0` when it has no children.

When adding a child, add the child's weight to the `Composite`'s weight. When removing a child, subtract its weight.

```
class Component(object): 
    def __init__(self,desc,weight=0,*args,**kw):
        self.parent = None
        self.desc = desc
        self.weight = weight

    def setParent(self,parent):
        self.parent=parent

    def getWeight(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Must instantiate subclass")

class Leaf(Component):
    def getWeight(self):
        return self.weight

class Composite(Component):
    def __init__(self,desc, *args, **kw):
        super(Composite,self).__init__(desc,*args, **kw)
        self.children = []

    def append_child(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)
        child.setParent(self)
        self.weight += child.getWeight()

    def remove_child(self, child):
        self.children.remove(child)
        self.weight -= child.getWeight()

    def getWeight(self):
        return self.weight
```

Here I demonstrate by adding `Leaf`s and `Composite`s as children of another `Composite`.

```
c1 = Composite("Composite 1")
c2 = Composite("Composite 2")

c1.append_child(Leaf("A leaf",5))
c1.append_child(Leaf("A leaf",5))
c1.append_child(Leaf("A leaf",5))

c2.append_child(Leaf("A leaf",1))
c2.append_child(Leaf("A leaf",1))
c2.append_child(Leaf("A leaf",1))

c1.append_child(c2)
```

### Output

```
In [2]: print(c1.getWeight())
18

In [3]: c1.remove_child(c2)
   ...: print(c1.getWeight())
   ...: 
15
```

Comment: this is also a solution but i am looking for solution like that; the totals should not be added or subtracted when items added or subtracted. In stead, after adding items i want to call a update() or calculate() function which is cumulatively sum the items and intermediate parents from bottom to top.